# Get current visible widget in ListView Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using `ListView.builder` , when we scroll up down,
how to get the currently visible widget in `viewport`.
something like Android `recyclerview` `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition`

Comment: What do you mean by currently visible widget? Is the the top most item or all the items which are visible in the `ListView`?

Comment: Yeah.. visible item in listview

Comment: Please read my comment again, which item you are talking about

Comment: Completely visible widgets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out which items in a ListView are visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57011733/find-out-which-items-in-a-listview-are-visible)

Answer (score -6):

Google gives the solution.

https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets (This repository contains the source code for various Flutter widgets that are developed by Google but not by the core Flutter team.)

Comment: try VisibilityDetector