# Find out which items in a ListView are visible

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

How can I find out which items are currently `visible` or `invisible` in a `ListView`?
For example, I have 100 items in `ListView` and when i scroll to top of screen or list, I want to detect which items appear or disappear from the viewport.

Illustration:

[image]

Comment: Why do you wanna know that? If you are going to make a list with 100 itens you should use `ListView.builder` witch you can pass a `itemBuilder`, that will build the 'widget' of a line in your `listView`. So the flutter will manage to you witch line is visible and render it, and clear from memory the invisible ones...

Comment: yes i know that as flutter can manage that. i want to use this feature for using another listeners to use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [inview_notifier_list](https://pub.dev/packages/inview_notifier_list). It's basically a normal ListView which defines a visible region and it's children get notified when they are in that region.

[image]

Comment: There example is not even working... I'm using flutter v2.8

Answer (score 16):

There is no easy way to do this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55197315/6509751) is the same question, however, it does not have an answer.

There is an active [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19941) about this.

There are multiple solutions for the problem in that issue. This [Gist](https://gist.github.com/debuggerx01/49f108d68ed903458e9478b4f0c186f4) features one that requires the [`rect_getter` package](https://pub.dev/packages/rect_getter).
Alternatively, you could take a look at [this proposal](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19941#issuecomment-486950990).

### TL;DR

This is not yet implemented if you are searching for an easy way to find it out. However, there are solutions, like the ones I mentioned above and from other packages, say [`VisibilityDetector`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_widgets/latest/flutter_widgets/VisibilityDetector-class.html) from [`flutter_widgets`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widgets).

Comment: Now there is an easy way to do it, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57252652/11246031

Comment: @LukasSchneider Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: thank u both u guys, also lukas answer seems to be good solution too!

Comment: does visibilityDetector has some limitations ? i couldn’t understand that from their pub documentation

Answer (score 3):

There is a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector) for this purpose.

> A VisibilityDetector widget wraps an existing Flutter widget and fires a callback when the widget's visibility changes.

Usage:

```
VisibilityDetector(
    key: Key('my-widget-key'),
    onVisibilityChanged: (visibilityInfo) {
      var visiblePercentage = visibilityInfo.visibleFraction * 100;
      debugPrint(
          'Widget ${visibilityInfo.key} is ${visiblePercentage}% visible');
    },
    child: someOtherWidget,
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

---

I'm Sharing for visibility on how to approach detecting position of widget in general.

I was curious as to how you access positional data of widgets, and also wanted to be able to control the animated state of a ListView child element.

Looks like the main point of access to a widgets, size and position is via the `BuildContext's` `context.findRenderObject()`

However, this is only usable after the component has been built and the widget is mounted.

This is addressed by using context.findRenderObject() in a function called using `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => calculatePosition(context));`

Here's a wrapper component you can use in your `ListView.itemBuilder()` code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

enum POCInViewDirection { up, down, static }

class POCInView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double scrollHeight;

  const POCInView({super.key, required this.child, required this.scrollHeight});

  @override
  POCInState createState() => POCInState();
}

class POCInState extends State<POCInView> {
  bool inView = false; // are you in view or not.
  double lastPositionY = 0; // used to determine which direction your widget is moving.
  POCInViewDirection direction = POCInViewDirection.static; // Set based on direction your moving.
  RenderBox? renderBoxRef;
  bool skip = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    developer.log('InitState', name: 'POCInView');
    lastPositionY = 0;
    renderBoxRef = null;
    direction = POCInViewDirection.static;
    skip = true;
  }
  /// Calculate if this widget is in view.
  /// uses BuildContext.findRenderObject() to get the RenderBox.
  /// RenderBox has localToGlobal which will give you the objects offset(position)
  /// Do some math to workout if you object is in view.
  /// i.e. take into account widget height and position.
  ///
  /// I only do Y coordinates.
  ///
  void calculatePosition(BuildContext context) {
    // findRenderObject() will fail if the widget has been unmounted. so leave if not mounted.
    if (!mounted) {
      renderBoxRef = null;
      return;
    }

    // It says this can be quite expensive as it will hunt through the view tree to find a RenderBox.
    // probably worth timing or seeing if its too much for you view.
    // I've put a rough cache in, deleting the ref when its unmounted. mmmmm.
    renderBoxRef ??= context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    //
    inView = false;
    if (renderBoxRef is RenderBox) {
      Offset childOffset = renderBoxRef!.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
      final double y = childOffset.dy;
      final double componentHeight = context.size!.height;
      final double screenHeight = widget.scrollHeight;
      if (y < screenHeight) {
        if (y + componentHeight < -20) {
          inView = false;
        } else {
          inView = true;
        }
      } else {
        inView = false;
      }

      // work out which direction we're moving. Not quite working right yet.
      direction = y > lastPositionY ? POCInViewDirection.down : POCInViewDirection.up;
      lastPositionY = y;

     //developer.log('In View: $inView, childOffset: ${childOffset.dy.toString()}', name: 'POCInView');
    }
    skip = false;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // calculate position after build is complete. this is required to use context.findRenderObject().
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => calculatePosition(context));

    // fade in when in view.
    final oChild = AnimatedOpacity(opacity: inView ? 1 : 0, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1), child: widget.child);

    // slide in when in view, and adjust slide direction based on scroll direction.
    return AnimatedSlide(
      duration: Duration(seconds: inView ? 1 : 0),
      offset: Offset(0, inView ? 0.0 : 0.25 * (skip == true ? 0 : (direction == POCInViewDirection.up ? 1 : -1))),
      child: oChild,
    );
  }
}
```